# Two loopback adapters communication in windows 7 or 8

Tags: windows-7, loopback

Once our development systems are upgraded from windows XP to windows 7, my debug setup has stopped working.
Steps followed in original setup (Windows XP):

1. Add two loopback adapters
2. Assign ipv4 172.16.16.1 to one adapter and 172.16.24.1 address to another adapter
3. Start an Java application (source code is with us) which will bind to 172.16.24.1 address
4. Start another Java application (source code is **not** with us), which will bind to 172.16.16.1

Both application will run on same machine and they will start communication to each other. Everything works!
I have followed the similar procedure in windows 7 and 8, but it did not worked.
I have captured the wireshark logs for both the loopback adapters and one packet for each are as follows:

**172.16.16.1**

```
Frame 58: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{6643679F-0401-414D-836C-1DAF07029D29})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Dec 29, 2015 16:10:34.776507000 India Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1451385634.776507000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 1.277163000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 1.277163000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 57.308582000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 58
    Frame Length: 42 bytes (336 bits)
    Capture Length: 42 bytes (336 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:arp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: ARP]
    [Coloring Rule String: arp]
Ethernet II, Src: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50)
    Type: ARP (0x0806)
Address Resolution Protocol (request)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (1)
    Protocol type: IPv4 (0x0800)
    Hardware size: 6
    Protocol size: 4
    Opcode: request (1)
    Sender MAC address: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50)
    Sender IP address: 172.16.16.1 (172.16.16.1)
    Target MAC address: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
    Target IP address: 172.16.24.1 (172.16.24.1)
```

**172.16.24.1**

```
Frame 31: 138 bytes on wire (1104 bits), 138 bytes captured (1104 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{4D43D976-8431-4537-B619-E810440F0221})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Dec 29, 2015 15:53:53.591436000 India Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1451384633.591436000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 2.500999000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 2.500999000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 72.662379000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 31
    Frame Length: 138 bytes (1104 bits)
    Capture Length: 138 bytes (1104 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:adwin_config]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
        Address: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address (multicast/broadcast)
    Source: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50)
        Address: 172.16.16.1 (02:00:4c:4f:4f:50)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.16.24.1 (172.16.24.1), Dst: 172.16.255.255 (172.16.255.255)
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 124
    Identification: 0x0c2a (3114)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xbe25 [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 172.16.24.1 (172.16.24.1)
    Destination: 172.16.255.255 (172.16.255.255)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 57488 (57488), Dst Port: 57488 (57488)
    Source Port: 57488
    Destination Port: 57488
    Length: 104
    Checksum: 0x662b [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    [Stream index: 0]
ADwin configuration protocol
    Pattern: Unknown (0x5359434e)
    Reboot: False
    MAC address: 39:3e:c2:5d:00:00 (39:3e:c2:5d:00:00)
    Unused
    Unused
```

Could somebody please point me in the direction to resolve this?

Comment: Can you ping both loopback adapter IPs?
Do both of them have the same subnet mask? Was a new loop back adapter created for each IP you wanted to use like in this link?
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/install-a-loopback-adapter-in-windows-7/ This link has some good information too:
http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18076/under-what-circumstances-are-multiple-loopback-127-8-addresses-useful Wonder if you need to have 127.0.0.X IPs rather than the 172.x.x.x that are being used. Would that break anything if you swapped IP addresses?

Comment: 1. Yes, I am able to ping both of them and they have same subnet mask. 2. Yes, both are created separately. 
3. As i do not have control over 172.16.16.1 application, thus i cannot change the IPs to 127 series.
Additionally, this setup works if I add two physical network cards and connect them via cross cable.

Comment: Well at least it's working that way. With that last comment. This might be an option if you wanted to eliminate the physical cable.
Create a bridge between the network connections.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-network-bridge